# how to scan a binary file for a virus signature in c?

Tags: c, file, binary

i'm tring to scan a binary file for a binary virus signture.

i worte this function:

```
int scanForVirus(FILE* fp,  char* virus)
{
    int result = 0;
    char temp[BUFSIZ];

    while (fgets(temp, BUFSIZ, fp) != NULL) 
    {
        printf("%s\n", temp);
        if ((strstr(temp, virus)) != NULL)
        {
            result = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

this is how i did the virus string(virus_file is also binary):

```
    FILE* virus_file = fopen(argv[2], "rb");

    fseek(virus_file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    long int res = ftell(virus_file);

    char* virus = (char*)malloc(res * sizeof(char));
    fgets(virus, res, virus_file);
```

and this is fp(all the dir stuff works good):

```
fp = fopen(dir->d_name, "rb");
```

the code crashs in the fgets in the function:

```
while (fgets(temp, BUFSIZ, fp) != NULL)
```

and i have no idea how to fix it.
TIA.

Comment: You won't get far with `strstr` if the binary file contains any zeros, and  `fgets()` is used with *text* files. I would use `fread()` and look for the first byte match with `memchr()` and then apply `memcmp()` whenever I get a match.

Comment: I agree with @WeatherVane. You probably shouldn't read binary files using `fgets`. Use `fread` instead and deal with the corner case that the beginning of your match is near the end of the read buffer.

Comment: 'printf("%s\n", temp);' is broken for the same reason.